# Canon lens 24-105mm macro error, please help

Tags: lens, canon

the body is great with 50mm lens
but, when I change the lens 105mm len,( 7 years old )
it have motor noise when attach to the body,
take photo will be error and hangs.
lens do not works, no focus, 
clean the connectors but same issue.

is there any way to block the connector and use it as manual lens ?
( I am thinking to repair it but the quote is expensive. )

thanks alot

Comment: why not change to MF via switch?

Comment: If you get an error, that probably points to something more like a broken aperture cable, rather than a focusing failure, which I would expect to just result in an out-of-focus image.  You can always tape over the contacts, but you probably ought to try to get the lens fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If a zoom lens throws error codes when the lens is extended and works properly when the lens is retracted, that's almost always an indication that one of the ribbon cables are cracked so that there are continuity errors when the cable is flexed in specific positions.

Depending upon exactly which camera body you are using, you can possibly tape off the lens contacts for AF and shoot manually. If that doesn't work, you can tape off all of the lens cables but that will only allow you to shoot with the aperture wide open (or with whatever position the aperture is in).